# Capture a video stream from rtsp camera and write it to a file

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

I am trying to capture a video stream coming from an rtsp camera and write it to a file. Using Jetson Xavier AGX with Jetpack 4.5 [L4T 32.5.0]

I am using below python app to perform the task:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtspsrc location=rtsp://10.34.134.1/Streaming/channels/1/ user-id=myuser user-pw=mypass !  rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink")

w = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
h = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
print('Src opened, %dx%d @ %d fps' % (w, h, fps))

gst_out = "appsrc ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test.mkv "
out = cv2.VideoWriter(gst_out, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, float(fps), (int(w), int(h)))
if not out.isOpened():
   print("Failed to open output")
   exit()

if cap.isOpened():
   while True:
      ret_val, img = cap.read()
      if not ret_val:
         break;
      out.write(img);
      cv2.waitKey(1)
else:
   print ("pipeline open failed")

cap.release()
out.release()
```

Opening the stream doesn’t work. I get the error below:

> [ERROR:0@0.041] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (164)
> open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:
>
> OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253:
> error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can’t find starting number (in
> the name of file): rtspsrc
> location=rtsp://10.34.134.1/Streaming/channels/1/ user-id=myuser
> user-pw=mypass ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv
> ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR !
> appsink in function ‘icvExtractPattern’

Can I somehow modify the string supplied to cv2.VideoCapture in order to properly read the rtsp stream?

Comment: is your opencv built with gstreamer? `getBuildInformation()` -- why do you not pass CAP_GSTREAMER to the VideoCapture constructor too?

Comment: It seems my opencv version is not built with gstreamer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your OpenCV came with GStreamer support, your `VideoCapture()` call should have worked. `CAP_GSTREAMER` would have recognized the pipeline string. That even works *without* explicitly specifying the backend.

Whenever OpenCV talks about `CAP_IMAGES`, that means no other backend felt responsible for the "target" and managed to "open" it. `CAP_IMAGES` is the lowest priority backend and is tried last.

When that happens, check the **Video I/O** section in the output of

```
import cv2 as cv
print(cv.getBuildInformation())
```

On Windows with an official package, this might look like so:

```
...
  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES
...
```

***If your build of OpenCV did not come with GStreamer***, you can build OpenCV yourself, with support for GStreamer, or you can look around for builds that come with it. Your operating system might have a package manager that provides a third party build of OpenCV with GStreamer support. Official packages don't include this, as far as I'm aware.

To make sure you are getting a specific backend, pass `cv.CAP_GSTREAMER` or another identifier for the `apiPreference` parameter of either `VideoCapture()` or `VideoWriter()` constructors.

```
cap = cv.VideoCapture(your_gst_pipeline, apiPreference=cv.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

Comment: Thanks @Christoph. The issue is due to opencv not being built with GStreamer.